# How to remove anomaly in burndown chart

Tags: azure-devops, burndowncharts

Mid way through the last quarter someone (for some unknown reason) changed the story point value of a user story to 2000. This is affecting the burndown graph for that period. Is there any way I can remove this anomaly? I know it's unlikely since then everyone would just remove the things they didn't want people to see but my burndown is a bit screwed otherwise :(

[Burndown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGKxC.png)

I have already tried deleting the offending user story but that doesn't fix the burndown. I'm hoping to be able to record the correct values for this user story in the burndown or, if not, be able to remove this user story from the burndown.